# Кнопка "Обзор" для выбора файла на сервере (картинки, или pdf)

Tags: html, html5, html-select

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать кнопку "Обзор" на сайте. Чтобы человек кликнув по ней выбирал файл не на компьютере, а какой-нибудь уже имеющийся файл на сервере.
Нужно что-то наподобие `<input type="file">`

Только `<input type="file">` используется для загрузки файлов на сервер, а мне нужно выбрать уже загруженный файл (картинку, или pdf) с помощью кнопки.

Comment: _уже загруженный файл_. Загруженный на сервер?

Comment: Да. У меня в папке documents есть pdf файлы. И нужно выбрать конкретный файл с помощью кнопки обзор, чтобы получить путь к этому файлу и записать этот путь в БД.